# Center editor screen on current editor line in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio

Is there a way of centering the editor view on the line where the editor cursor is? Sometimes I end up with the cursor on the last of first visible line in the editor screen, and it would be helpful to be able to quickly center on that line with a keyboard shortcut.

I tried looking at scripting, but did not manage to find a suitable command.

Comment: use the `GoTo` function in the context menu. place cursor on line in source code, right click, `Go to PDF`, done. works vice versa. or press `CTRL+ left click`. see section 4.9 in the manual

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way of centering the editor screen on the cursor in the editor, not the document viewer.

Comment: there's no function to do that. you could place a feature request at the developer site.

Comment: This is really contingent on how large your editor window is (how many lines can be shown), and I'm not quite 100% sure whether this can be inferred through script. There is a `editor.scrollToFirstLine(linenum)` function though, which takes the line at `linenum` and sets it as the first line in your editor. You can try tweaking `editor.scrollToFirstLine(cursor.lineNumber()-15)`, for example, but you'll have to change this number whenever you close/open the find panel / bottom panel, for instance.